# Watch not firing in a directive with isolate scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was attempting to do something with D3 and Angular. I am not sure that this is something to do with D3 at all but have left it in there just so I could reproduce all that I was trying..

Here is a plunk that reproduces my problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/sxbKUmeb1B51t9eTtgwH?p=preview

What I am attempting to do is, create data array and produce a set of d3 svg circles based on that data. The directive created should "watch" this data array and create or delete more circles based on the array shrinking or expanding.. I think the logic is pretty simple to follow from there. To ensure that I do this at a later time, I am doing the addition of a new value into the array using $timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off, this code:
`<circles data="obj.dataArray"></circles>` seems wrong because you don't define `dataArray` anywhere on `obj` in your scope.

So this:

```
function($scope,model,$timeout) {
    $scope.obj = {};
        model.data[0] = 20;
        model.data[1] = 30;
        model.data[2] = 40;
        model.data[3] = 50;

        $timeout(function(){

            model.data.push(Math.random()*100);
            console.log(model.data);
        },1000);
}
```

Should probably be some like this:

```
function($scope,model,$timeout) {
    $scope.model = model;
    $scope.model.data[0] = 20;
    $scope.model.data[1] = 30;
    $scope.model.data[2] = 40;
    $scope.model.data[3] = 50;

    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.model.data.push(Math.random()*100);
        console.log($scope.model.data);
    },1000);
}
```

And this: `<circles data="obj.dataArray"></circles>` should be `<circles data="model"></circles>`.

Now in your directive, you've set up the scope like this:

```
scope : {
    data : '&'
},
```

but that should be:

```
scope : {
    data : '='
},
```

since you want a reference to the object represented by the data attribute. & are for when attributes contain expressions that you want to execute.

So with those changes, scope.data in your directive now contains a reference to your "commonModel", so there's no longer any need for the directive to ask for "commonModel". Then change your $watch to watch on "data.length" to know when items have been added or removed to it.

Something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/sa9blROCm8FFhRQSEWii

Comment: Awesome, thanks.. Some of the things you mentioned earlier were actually "remains" from my different attempts. I initially tried it with just a scope object in the controller as in this plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0n0MlwtwYTnWt5S3wd1?p=preview , that dint dint work, then I attempted with a service ( which you see there ) and even that did not work!! I tried a reference to that object ( scope.obj.data instead of scope.data ) and that dint help either.

Comment: It looks like the thing that fixed this is actually watching scope.data.length instead of watching scope.data... I am still not clear as to why watching length works while watching the object itself doesnt!!! Maybe I should watch with deepwatch set to true... Good one though.. thanx..

Comment: Your watch expressions should be as quick as possible since they are executed for every digest, so watching for data.length is fine if you're only interested of knowing when elements are added/removed. If you really need a watch on the whole data structure, you can pass "true" as a third argument to $watch, and that will tell Angular to watch by value instead of by reference. But think twice before you do that, since it comes with a performance penalty.